# Poisson distribution - find value for $\lambda$ given a known probability

Tags: poisson-distribution

Particles in a radioactive piece of material are decaying, and it is known that the number of decayed particles during a time period t (sec) is $Po(\lambda t)$-distributed. It is also known that the probability of there being at least one particle that has decayed during 60 seconds is 0.5. What value for $\lambda$ is the appropriate one to use in this model for radio active decay?

I am stumped on how to approach this problem. In particular I do not know how to make use of the given probability - P(at least one particle has decayed during a 60 second period)=0.5.

Comment: Try to look at the complementary event "no particles decayed during a $60$-second period". What is its probability? How do you write it in terms of $\lambda$ and $t$? CAn you find $\lambda$ now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
P(\text{at least one particle has decayed during a $60$ second}) = 0.5 \\
P(\text{at least one particle has decayed during a $60$ second}) = 1- P(\text{$0$ particle has decayed during a $60$ second}) 
\end{cases}
\\
\Rightarrow 
&P(\text{$0$ particle has decayed during a $60$ second})= 1-0.5 = 0.5  \quad (1)
\end{align}

By using $(1)$, we have
\begin{align}
&P(k \text{ events in 60 second}) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\times \lambda^{k}}{k!} \Rightarrow \\
&P(0 \text{ events in 60 second}) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\times \lambda^{0}}{0!} = 0.5 \Rightarrow e^{-\lambda} = 0.5 \Rightarrow \lambda = - ln(0.5)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank-you Hasan! Very clear solution.